# Accessing .env environment variables in the middleware kernel constructor

Tags: php, laravel-5

It seems that in the `Middleware Kernel constructor()` eventhough I have access to the `env('')` helper all my variables set in the .env file are returning null.

Why is this happening?

I actually wanted to set a config in my .env that the middleware reads so as to facilitate local development behaviors.

This is what I'm doing in my Http\Kernel

```
public function __construct(Application $app, Router $router)
{
    if (env('check_env_key', false)) {

    }
    parent::__construct($app, $router);
}
```

Comment: can you access variables in other places e.g. controller? and what OS are you working on?

Comment: Yes I can access it for example in the routes.php if I do env('checl_env_key') i get my value, but from the constructor above I get null. I'm developing on windows 8.1 php 5.6 (vagrant)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing in my Laravel 5.2 application. I dived into the code with help of xdebug.

To give answer to your question 'Why is this happening'?

If you look at the HttpKernel constructor (which is the parent of the Kernel), you see the env values are not loaded yet. See the $_ENV container in xdebug or dump it.

So the php function that collects the value for you ([getenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)) will return false. And, because of that false, the Laravel env helper will return the default value.

ROUTES
In the routes file the $_ENV container is filled with all your env values, so the expected value is returned.

It's a matter of timing. The expected behavior is not available yet in the kernel. That's why... :-)

I think Laravel loads the env-values when it's bootstrapping the application, not before.